# Add image to sidebar module

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit a website through Wordpress, but I'm not sure how to add an image to a sidebar.

In simple terms, what I want is for this page: https://www.kushnerhamed.com/attorneys/jeffrey-d-ubersax/

to have an image above the "Education" section like this page: https://www.kushnerhamed.com/attorneys/brandon-mordue/.

From what I could find, it involves using widgets, but they aren't in the Wordpress version I'm using (5.2.3). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets have been around [since version 2.8](https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-2-8/).

You could add this to your functions.php file. [As stated in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#examples).

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
function my_register_sidebars() {
    /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id'            => 'primary',
            'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar' ),
            'description'   => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        )
    );
    /* Repeat register_sidebar() code for additional sidebars. */
}
```

The widget should now be available in the Widgets section of the Wordpress Admin. 
Then you can add this to your theme template file to make the widget viewable in the front-end.

```
<div id="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?>
</div>
```